# error message is error Command failed with signal "SIGSEGV"

Tags: reactjs, webpack, npm-install

I'm using taro to make a small program, and I don't know what's wrong with my package.json that makes my program not run. Its error message is error Command failed with signal "SIGSEGV".
My package.json configuration file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "publish",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "",
  "templateInfo": {
    "name": "default-youshu",
    "typescript": true,
    "css": "sass"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:weapp": "taro build --type weapp",
    "build:swan": "taro build --type swan",
    "build:alipay": "taro build --type alipay",
    "build:tt": "taro build --type tt",
    "build:qq": "taro build --type qq",
    "dev:weapp": "npm run build:weapp -- --watch",
    "dev:swan": "npm run build:swan -- --watch",
    "dev:alipay": "npm run build:alipay -- --watch",
    "dev:tt": "npm run build:tt -- --watch",
    "dev:qq": "npm run build:qq -- --watch"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 3 versions",
    "Android >= 4.1",
    "ios >= 8"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.7",
    "@tarojs/components": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/helper": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/plugin-framework-react": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/plugin-html": "^3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/plugin-platform-alipay": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/plugin-platform-h5": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/plugin-platform-jd": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/plugin-platform-qq": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/plugin-platform-swan": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/plugin-platform-tt": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/plugin-platform-weapp": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/react": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/runtime": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/shared": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/taro": "3.6.2",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "sr-sdk-wxapp": "^1.3.6",
    "taro-axios": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.0",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.5",
    "@tarojs/cli": "3.6.2",
    "@tarojs/webpack5-runner": "3.6.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.20.0",
    "babel-preset-taro": "3.6.2",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-taro": "3.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "react-refresh": "^0.11.0",
    "stylelint": "9.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack": "5.69.0"
  }
}
```

I tried deleting node_module and re-npm install. However it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it by closing the terminal and opening again.
Deleting the folder `node_modules` and `. parcel`.
And then run:

`npm install`

`yarn install`